# iterate two recursive arrays [array item contains another array] simulataniously in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops, recursion

I have two arrays of objects it may contains another array of objects, how can i iterate with two arrays and compare with each other ???

```
interface items {
name:string;
subItems:items[];
value:string;
}

Array A=['parent1',['child1',['child2',['child3',[],'value3'],'value2'],'value1']];

Array B=['parent1',['child1',[null,['child3',[],'value3'],'value2'],'value1']];
```

**expected result :**

```
Array B=['parent1',['child1',['child2',['child3',[],'value3'],'value2'],'value1']];
```

difference between this two arrays is Array B child2 name is null, so i want to compare with two arrays and if name is null then copy the name from first array..

how we can iterate two arrays simultaneously  which may contains sub arrays.

note: some times my array CONTAINS N NUMBER OF CHILDREN'S,

i think we can do with recursive function but how we can iterate the level of arrays ?

i tried multiple for and forEach loops it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take both array into a function which iterates the elements and looks either for arrays, then call this function again or check the value and if different, then update the array.

```js
function compareAndUpdate(a, b) {
    a.forEach((v, i) => {
        if (Array.isArray(v)) return compareAndUpdate(v, b[i]);
        if (b[i] !== v) b[i] = v;
    });
}

var a = ['parent1', ['child1', ['child2', ['child3', [], 'value3'], 'value2'], 'value1']],
    b = ['parent1', ['child1', [null, ['child3', [], 'value3'], 'value2'], 'value1']];

compareAndUpdate(a, b);

console.log(b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you  so much for your idea i made some as per my code its working like charm

Answer (score 0):

This is Javascript solution. May be this can help:

```
    function recursion(arr1,arr2){

       for(let index = 0; (arr1.length>index && arr2.length>index);index++){
            if(Array.isArray(arr1[index]) && Array.isArray(arr2[index])){
                recursion(arr1[index],arr2[index]);
            }else if(arr1[index] !== arr2[index]){
                arr1[index] = arr2[index];
            }
       }
    }
```